# Unable to build golang app in docker

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

I have made a golang app using sample example, however when I setup docker to build and run it it fails to build giving the error

```
ERROR: for goserver  Cannot start service goserver: b'OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \\"./app\\": stat ./app: no such file or directory": unknown'
```

My Dockerfile is

```
FROM golang:1.8
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix nocgo -o ./app .
ENTRYPOINT ["./app"]
```

and my docker-compose is

```
version: '2'

volumes:
 app_nm:
 driver: local

services:
 goserver:
  container_name: "goserver"
  image: "mygoserver"
  build:
   context: ./First
   dockerfile: Dockerfile
  volumes:
   - ./First:/usr/src/app
  ports:
   - 8081:8080
  tty: true
```

I tried logging into container via docker exec by setting tty: true and executing the build command and it works fine. What could be the issue?

Comment: Does that folder exist in the container?

Comment: @janDro yup able to cd to directory /usr/src/app and see files there

Comment: And `First` also on the host?

Comment: @janDro yup its there in host and in it there is an app.go file with code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51917779/965900

Comment: Yeah either @mkopriva 's link or I'd suggest messing around with the permissions of the First directory and make sure it has execute on it. Also refer to -> https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4039

Comment: @mkopriva thanks it worked.. is there anyway to do hotloading for  go

Comment: @AnoopKrishnan I don't have any experience with hot reloading go projects, so the best I can offer is this: https://www.google.com/search?q=golang+hot+reload.

Comment: @AnoopKrishnan I use [**fresh**](https://github.com/pilu/fresh), and I'm pretty satisfied with it. On the other note your Dockerfile is quite strange.

Answer (score 1):

What looks off to me is that you are setting the working directory to /usr/src/app but then you are running go build ./app. Try changing ./app to just .